# How to split on the basis of ' in Rust

Tags: rust

This program is designed to check the number of occurrences of each word in a string. Every test ran successfully except when `words = "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."` or `words = "First: don't laugh. Then: don't cry."`.
If I get rid of `!c.is_alphanumeric()` in split closure, then I would have to write every single special character on which the words have to be split.

This a beginner level exercise on Exercism so I wanted to avoid regex crate.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn word_count(words: &str) -> HashMap<String, u32> {
    let mut indexes: HashMap<String, u32> = HashMap::new();
    let to_lowercase = words.to_lowercase();

    for c in to_lowercase.split(|c: char| !c.is_alphanumeric()).filter(|&x| x!="").collect::<Vec<&str>>(){


        let entry = indexes.entry(c.to_string()).or_insert(0);
        *entry += 1;
    };    

    indexes
}
```

Some tests

```
fn check_word_count(s: &str, pairs: &[(&str, u32)]) {
    // The reason for the awkward code in here is to ensure that the failure
    // message for assert_eq! is as informative as possible. A simpler
    // solution would simply check the length of the map, and then
    // check for the presence and value of each key in the given pairs vector.
    let mut m: HashMap<String, u32> = word_count(s);
    for &(k, v) in pairs.iter() {
        assert_eq!((k, m.remove(&k.to_string()).unwrap_or(0)), (k, v));
    }
    // may fail with a message that clearly shows all extra pairs in the map
    assert_eq!(m.iter().collect::<Vec<(&String, &u32)>>(), vec![]);
}


fn with_apostrophes() {
    check_word_count(
        "First: don't laugh. Then: don't cry.",
        &[
            ("first", 1),
            ("don't", 2),
            ("laugh", 1),
            ("then", 1),
            ("cry", 1),
        ],
    );
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
fn with_quotations() {
    check_word_count(
        "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large.",
        &[
            ("joe", 1),
            ("can't", 1),
            ("tell", 1),
            ("between", 1),
            ("large", 2),
            ("and", 1),
        ],
    );
}
```

Comment: My version of this exercise did not test for words containing contractions.  Is this phrase in your test suite?

Comment: Does you want 'large' and large to be seen as distinct words?

Comment: [Don't cross-post.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241619/how-to-split-on-the-basis-of-in-rust)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends on the definition of "word" from the point of view of the rules.  If you simply include the single-quote `'` as one of the characters that will not cause a word split, then you will include

- all contractions, and
- all words that have quotes around them (as distinct word types)

The following code prevents a split on a single-quote:

```
let single_quote: char = '\'';
....
split( |c: char| !c.is_alphanumeric() && c != single_quote)
```

This will see `'large'` as a word distinct from `large`, which might not be what you want, but again, the rules are not clear.

And, here is my full program.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn word_count(words: &str) -> HashMap<String, u32> {
    let mut indexes: HashMap<String, u32> = HashMap::new();
    let to_lowercase = words.to_lowercase();
    let single_quote: char = '\'';

    for c in to_lowercase.split
    ( |c: char| !c.is_alphanumeric() && c != single_quote)
        .filter(|x| !x.is_empty())
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>(){

        let entry = indexes.entry(c.to_string()).or_insert(0);
        *entry += 1;
    };    

   indexes
}

fn main(){
    let phrase = "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large.";
    let indices = word_count(phrase);
    println!("Phrase: {}", phrase);
    for (word,index) in indices {
        println!("word: {}, count: {}", word, index);
    }
}
```

And, here is the output from my main() routine.

```
Phrase: Joe can't tell between 'large' and large.
word: joe, count: 1    
word: can't, count: 1  
word: 'large', count: 1
word: and, count: 1    
word: between, count: 1
word: tell, count: 1   
word: large, count: 1
```